# Constructing objects with Xml parameters during Deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I've just recently started working with C# and learned about the great XmlSerializer the .NET framework has.

I've annotated a class like so:

```
    [XmlRoot("time_entry")]
    public class TimeEntry
    {
        [XmlElement("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("project"), XmlAttribute("id")]
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }

        [....]
    }
```

I can already do basic deserialization with :

```
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(T);
s.Deserialize(response.GetResponseStream());
```

Where T is a generic type. My goal now is to take this a step further, and given this XML :

```
<time_entries type="array" limit="25" offset="0" total_count="254">
    <time_entry>
        <id>299</id>
        <project id="152" name="Test"/>
        <issue id="1314"/>
        <user id="2" name="Anonymous"/>
        <activity id="9" name="Development"/>
        <hours>10.0</hours>
        <comments/>
        <spent_on>2015-11-09</spent_on>
        <created_on>2015-11-10T17:31:57Z</created_on>
        <updated_on>2015-11-10T17:31:57Z</updated_on>
    </time_entry>
</time_entries>
```

Automatically find the Project with the given id in an existing dictionary and instead of setting the `ProjectId` attribute on the `TimeEntry` class, i'd replace it with an instance of `Project` that i'd have found using the `id` attribute on the `<project>` XML element.

Is this somehow possible? I was thinking maybe of doing something immediately in the getter but as soon as the type of the field changes, it seems like the `<project>` element gets skipped

PS: I'm not really concerned with the Serialization process so the classes won't be serialized back to Xml...

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing IXmlSerializable on TimeEntry to get full control on how the object is deserialized. During deserialization you can assign an existing instance of Project.